# How to implement priority queue with redis

Tags: java, redis, priority-queue

Now I have such a requirement, publish tasks to the task queue, and then take tasks from the task queue one by one and execute them. When the tasks are taken from the queue, they are taken according to the priority size, and the tasks with the larger priority are taken out first. If the priorities are the same, the ones that join the queue earlier are taken out first compared with the time they join the queue.
This can be done in java through priorityQueue:

```
PriorityQueue: new PriorityQueue<>((t1, t2) ->! t1.getPriority().equals(t2.getPriority()) ?  t2.getPriority() - t1.getPriority() :(t1.getTime() - t2.getTme()));
```

But I want you to implement it in redis

This is the way I do it now, but it's a little crude and not very accurate
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jQrI5.png)

Comment: Please review the [ask] link to see how to best ask questions on the site. One take-away is to never post code as an image since it is extremely hard for anyone to copy/paste/compile and run code in this form. Please post your code as code-formatted text, and please add additional text that fully explains it.

Answer (score 0):

You solution is not thread-safe. You can try the following Lua script to implement the push part:

```
-- push.lua

redis.replicate_commands()

local key = KEYS[1]
local task_id = ARGV[1]
local priority = ARGV[2]

local t = redis.call("time")
local time_s = t[1]

-- original wrong answer: local score = priority * 10000000000 + time_s
local score = priority * 10000000000 + (10000000000 - time_s)

redis.call("zadd", key, score, task_id)
```

Push some items into the priority queue:

```
redis-cli --eval push.lua queue , task-id priority
```

Pop an item:

```
redis-cli zpopmax queue
```

Comment: Why "priority * 10000000000 + time_s" instead of "priority * 10000000000 - time_s"? The priority is the same, the smaller the time should be first out of the queue